# How to remove the git remote origin and add new remote origin?

Tags: git, github, git-remote

I have cloned the code from one git repo of another person and now I want to commit the code to my git repo. How I can do this without copy-pasting post-checkout separately?

Any git reference would be more helpful.

Comment: you can direct modify config File in ".git" folder. The folder is hidden you can show it by window explorer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Run the below commands in sequence:

- `git remote`

> Will get the current remote path

- `git remote remove <remote path>`

> So now your remote link will be deleted, now you can add your repo and commit your changes, anyway confirm whether the remote has been deleted using below command

- `git remote`

> Nothing should be displayed

- `git remote add origin <your git repo http path>`

> Now your repo will be added as git repo to this folder, so now push your code changes to the new repo using below command.

- `git push origin master`

Comment: `git remove remote google
git: 'remove' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Comment: it should be `git remote remove <remote name>`

Comment: And If we have two remote origins, how to specify one of them ?

Answer (score 0):

I would do a git remote -v , instead of git remote just to make sure that the full origin url(path) is right